# which one is expensive operation in rails 3.x Model.new or Model.update?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Which of following operations are faster in Rails 3.2

```
Fact.delete    
Fact.new(:balance => 233, :profit_date => Date.now, :comments => "whatever")
```

OR

```
Fact.update(:balance => 233, :profit_date => Date.now, :comments => "whatever")
```

Comment: Doesn't matter, they do different things. You're asking whether apples are faster than oranges. Regardless, this can't possibly be answered without knowing a lot more about your database structure. The only thing we can advise is that you actually benchmark each, and find out which is faster *for you*, as neither is "faster" in all possible cases.

Comment: Sorry I was editing you answered. I was wrong in explaining the question. which of above is faster ?

Comment: Again, why are you asking us? It's trivially easy to benchmark this yourself, and find out *for your situation*, which is the faster option. Your code still doesn't make sense though; Why are you calling delete/update on the model, instead of an instance of the model?

Comment: This is a Q&A forum that's why I am asking people not you!!. The idea here is to quickly understand rather then spending time in understanding how these operations work. If I have to find out answer of everything that can be answer, why would you think I am on this forum ???. There is nothing wrong to ask questions if even they are silly. You can tell me how to benchmark rather than giving me penalties.

Comment: Or, you could go test this yourself. As I said, nobody can answer this for you with no idea of how your database is set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two code snippets your include would do different things, if they worked:

The first piece of code won't work, because you're calling `.new` on `fact`, which is an *instance* of a class, not the class itself. It probably doesn't have a `.new` method, and if it does, it's probably not going to do what you want. To create a new Fact object, you would  use `Fact.new`. But even if you do that, ActiveRecord's `.new` method **does not save the record**. Thus, `fact.delete; Fact.new` only deletes the record, it does not save one. Use `Fact.create()` if you want to create and save a record (or `fact = Fact.new()` followed by `f.save`).

The second piece also wouldn't work, because the method you want is named `.update_attributes`, not `.update`. You'd get an error.

Now, as to the actual question of which is faster, deleting a record and then recreating it or just updating it: The best way to find which of two things is faster is to benchmark it yourself. This is because the answer will depend on how your database is set up, how many records it has in it, and any number of other factors. It seems sensible to me that `DELETE` followed by `INSERT` is going to be slower than `UPDATE`, but that's not the same as actually testing it, and any test I did would be based on *my* database setup instead of yours.

Unless you're planning to do this a very large number of times, both methods are probably 'fast enough'. Given that, I'd use `.update_attributes` regardless of it's relative performance, because the code will make more sense and be more readable that way. If you *are* doing it many times, you'll get much larger performance gains by refactoring to do a bulk update in some way.

Comment: Cool!. Sorry about fact, it is Fact (Model) actually.

Comment: @amjad Remember that when you're creating a new instance of a model, you call `.new` or `.create` *on the model class* (`Fact.new`), but if you're updating or deleting, you call those methods on an instance of the model (`f = Fact.new` then `f.save`).

Comment: It is just on Model called Fact with one database (mysql) and table is fact_table.

Comment: understood. someone is getting offended with my silly questions :)